# javascript generate combinations of arrays of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, iterator

how to find cartesian product of identical arrays? (handshake problem).

I found cart_prod() and cartesianProductOf() functions which works okay, but when I do:

cart_prod(list1, list1)

instead of giving me an array of size (n^2+n)/2 I get an array of size n^2. Basically it returns to me all permutations instead of combinations. I am crossing two lists because it's sort of like a handshake-like problem.

here is the cartesianProductOf() function:

```
function cartesianProductOf() {
//better cartesian function
//usage: cartesianProductOf([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]) returns 8 arrays [1,3,6],[1,3,5] and so on.
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
    var ret = [];
    a.forEach(function(a) {
      b.forEach(function(b) {
        ret.push(a.concat([b]));
      });
    });
    return ret;
  }, [[]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to be fancy here... you can solve this with just a for loop. (The trick is enforcing an ordering i

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length. i++){
    for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
        //do something with the i-th and j-th elements of the array
    }
}
```

---

BTW, a cartesian product is *supposed* to give N^2 elements in the example you gave. And it i